# can anyone identify this wild plant from irish pasture?

Tags: identification

i just bought some hay here in the west of ireland. i've discovered this weed and i cant seem to identify it... it has a hairy fibrous stem and what i can only desribe as a flower pod, which i opened up to find a mass of tiny flowers waiting to come out, which i can only assume would grow out something like ground elder or alexanders (horse parsely), however neither of those have a hairy stem as far as i know.

I'm fairly stumped! mainly, i'm trying to ascertain if its safe for horses to eat.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did it burn your skin when the sap touched it while exposed to the light? If so, it's cow parsnip.